# Unexpected output while trying to display the temperature closest to zero (java)

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
import java.util.*;
class Solution
{

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int c=5526;
        int inp;
        for(int a=0;a<n;a++)
        {
            inp=sc.nextInt();
            if(Math.abs(inp)<c)
            {
                c=inp;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(c);
    }
}
```

Input:
[image: Inputs]

Error:
[image: Error]

I don't know what the problem is, I cant *try* anything cuz I don't even know where the bug is.

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: HOw did you get a negative value for c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to display the temperature closest to `0`, i.e. the temperature whose absolute value is smallest. The code presented is already pretty close. There is just one small bug in this line:

```
if (Math.abs(inp) < c)
```

We compare the absolute value of `inp` against the value of `c`. Looking at the body of the `if`, we see that `c` is set to the value of `inp`. The value of `inp` can be negative, thus `c` can be negative. Going back to the `if`-condition: as soon as `c` is negative, `Math.abs(inp) < c` will always evaluate to `false`. Hence, we have to also take the absolute value of `c` in the condition:

```
if (Math.abs(inp) < Math.abs(c))
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/BfQxdN)

This will produce the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not asked properly but nevertheless, I will try to answer according to my best understanding. So the problem is when you run the program you are entering input in the wrong way for example you enter the number of temperatures that will be compared and then add the temperatures one after the other which in this case it is not accepted as a valid number instead it should be followed by Enter. Also, your code is not producing the correct result you have a logic error.